# Does anybody know if manifest.xml (wsp) has an intellisense for Visual Studio?

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2007, intellisense, wsp

I've been searching for intellisense in Visual Studio 2005 or Visual Studio 2008 when editing "*manifest.xml*" file in a SharePoint solution (wsp) with no result. Does anybody know if there is something similar to CAML intellisense but for "*manifest.xml*" files???

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can ensure intellisense by adding schema references to wss.xsd, coredefinitions.xsd, CamlQuery.xsd and camlview.xsd contained in c:\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\web server extensions\12\Template\Xml

TO do so, with your manifest file open in VS.NET, go to the Properties window, and in the Schemas property you can click the browse button and load these schemas.

If you search Google (I think Andrew Connell has a sample) there are ways to force this to occur for every xml file as well.

Answer (score 1):

Intellisense in XML in Visual Studio depends on the presence of an XML schema file in the folder:

C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 9.0\Xml\Schemas

(or the equivalent for the version you are using). So if you can find an XML schema for these files, you can enable Intellisense.

The file you need is DeploymentManifest.xsd, described here:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb263776.aspx